# How to create view pager in YouTubeBaseActivity?

Tags: android, youtube-api, android-youtube-api

I want created a view pager below youtube view in YoubeBaseActivity . But when I call

```
adap = new AdapterPagerFragment(getSupportFragmentManager(),
            getApplication());
```

It show error in getSupportFragmentManager(). How I can fix it or create a viewpager in YoubeBaseActivity?
Thank every one!

Answer (score 0):

Use [YouTubePlayerSupportFragment](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/reference/com/google/android/youtube/player/YouTubePlayerSupportFragment#Overview) if you are only playing a YouTube video in a single `support.v4.app.Fragment`. This allows you to use FragmentActivity.

You need to [`initialize`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/reference/com/google/android/youtube/player/YouTubePlayerSupportFragment#public-constructors) a [YouTubePlayer](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/reference/com/google/android/youtube/player/YouTubePlayer) to create a YouTube fragment. `public YouTubePlayerSupportFragment ()` this constructor is public only for use by an inflater. Use [`newInstance()`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/reference/com/google/android/youtube/player/YouTubePlayerSupportFragment#Public_Methods) to create a `YouTubePlayerSupportFragment` programmatically.

Comment: thank you, I have viewpager without fragment. It done.